# "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence" Assigning the mean value of the neighboor of a point in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a numpy array that contains the coordinates (X,Y,Z) of 5 points:

```
Coordinates = np.array([[1000, 1000,10],[1003, 1003,10],[1004, 1004,10],[1002, 1002,10],[1001, 1001,10]])
```

On the other hand, I have a Pandas dataframe that contains the value of a variable for each of these 5 points:

```
d = {"Values": [0.25, 0.24,0.23,0.3,0.22]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

With treeBall_Neighbors I get the index of the neighbors of each point within a radius of 2m:

```
treeBall_Neighbors = sklearn.neighbors.BallTree(Coordinates, leaf_size=2)
indices_Neighbors=treeBall_Neighbors.query_radius(Coordinates[:], r=2)
```

And finally I want to add the mean value of the neighbors of each point into the dataframe:

```
df["Neighbors_Values"]=df["Values"].iloc[indices_Neighbors.tolist()[:]].mean()
```

But sadly I'm getting the error "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence". The only partial solution that I get was only for the first row:

```
df["Neighbors_Values"]=df["Values"].iloc[indices_Neighbors.tolist()[0]].mean()
```

Do you have any idea of how can I obtain the other values without do a loop? The final result should looks like this:

```
   Values  Neighbors_Values
0    0.25             0.235
1    0.24             0.256667
2    0.23             0.235
3    0.30             0.253333
4    0.22             0.256667
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resolved the problem with the following code (using a function and lambda):

```
def Obtain_Mean(x, df):
    print(df.Values.iloc[x.indices_Neighbors].mean())
    return df.Values.iloc[x.indices_Neighbors].mean()
    
    #inFile["Neighbors_Z"][i]=inFile["NDVI"].iloc[indices_Neighbors.tolist()[i]].mean()


Coordinates = np.array([[1000, 1000,10],[1003, 1003,10],[1004, 1004,10],[1002, 1002,10],[1001, 1001,10]])
d = {"Values": [0.25, 0.24,0.23,0.3,0.22]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
treeBall_Neighbors = sklearn.neighbors.BallTree(Coordinates, leaf_size=2)
indices_Neighbors=treeBall_Neighbors.query_radius(Coordinates[:], r=2)


df["indices_Neighbors"]=indices_Neighbors
df['Mean_Neighbors'] = df.apply(lambda x: Obtain_Mean(x, df) , axis=1)
```